# Does Unity need system images in the SDK folder?

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine, sdk, android-emulator

So my computer has limited disk space, and i noticed that the system-images folder in the SDK folder takes up 6.54GB of space. I read that these images are only needed for emulators, which i do not use in Unity development.

So can somebody tell me if it is safe to delete these without any errors occuring?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You could move/rename the folder and check to make sure nothing you actually want to do breaks.  After using  Unity like that for a while to insure the files are safe to remove permanently, you can delete them.  If something *does* cause a problem, you can restore the files easily.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: Okay, so everything builds fine. For removing the system images, is it best to delete them through the SDK manager or just deleting the file manually? @Draco18s

Comment: I don't think it matters.  If you remove them manually, Unity will see that they are gone and do any cleanup when Unity becomes the active window again.  If you delete them through the SDK manager that cleanup would happen immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Draco18s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via comments, turns out these files are safe to remove (discovered by "try it and see" which I would not ordinarily offer as an "answer").

Glad to have helped.